# How to store the output of the function as a matrix with specific name of columns and rows in r?

Tags: r

I simulate a mixture data for 10 runs. Then aplied my function to all runs using apply function. Now I will get 10 different results of my function. I would like to save my output as a matrix with chosen name of my column and row. For example I would like to get the output as follows:

```
 dist = rnorm(n=100, m=2, sd=2.2)
 rep. = function (dist) { 
 replicate(n=2, dist)
 list(mean(dist), mode(dist),sd(dist)
 }
```

I would like to find the mode, mean and sd as a matrix for the 2 runs. That is:

```
   Iteration.     Mean   Mode  sd
    1              0.5.   3    0.4
    2              0.3    1    0.6
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: My code is too long, I will provide a small code to make sure that my question is understandable.

Comment: I included some explanation with some code.

Comment: @Samuel I edit my question and hope that it is clear now. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there isn't a function `mode()` in base R. So I provide one for you:

```
mode <- function(x){
  dd <- density(x)
  dd$x[which.max(dd$y)]
}
```

Second, you need to wrap your code inside a call to replicate. Your code doesn't do anything at all with the replicate. It replicates `print(dist)` twice and then calculates the mean, mode and sd only once.

Third: If you want to do this on random generated vectors, also the `rnorm()` call has to be inside the replicate.
Don't export a list object and let `replicate` do the job for you.

Forth: `replicate()` returns by default a matrix with names if necessary. That's what the arguments `simplify` and `USE.NAMES` exist in the first place. Keep in mind that `replicate` binds the results together as columns. So to have a matrix where you have a column for mean, one for mode and one for sd, you need to transpose it.

So what you want to do, is better solved by:

```
out <- replicate(n=2,{
  x <- rnorm(n = 100, m = 2, sd = 2.2)
  c(mean = mean(x),
    mode = mode(x),
    sd = sd(x)
  )
})
t(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
replicate(n = 2, expr = x <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 2, sd = 2.2)) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  summarize_all(c("mean", "sd"))
```

There is no function in base R for calculating the mode, so I suggest you do that in a separate function as described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_mean_median_mode.htm). However, calculating the mode does not make much sense in this case since the mean = median = mode for the normal distribution.

Comment: There's no reason to use `apply(d, 2, mean)`. The function `colMeans(d)` works a lot faster. Plus, your code generates the exact same vector every time. So all your means are the exact same, all your sd's are the exact same.

Comment: Thanks @JorisMeys for spotting this. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You still have the same problem. If you want to generate multiple random vectors, you have to put the call to `rnorm()` inside the expression you give as a second argument to `replicate()`. You still just evaluate `x` twice. That will give you twice the exact same vector, being the result of the previous call to `rnorm()`. And `dplyr` isn't helping you out here either, as you have to convert to data frame and end up with a tibble actually.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did first. I don't know why I changed it, for clarity I guess, not realizing it totally changed the randomization procedure. Thanks for taking the time to point this out!